# Class does not exist while adding custom class

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 and auth plugin.

Folder structure

Laravel

- App

  - Customfolder

    - Utilities

      - RegisQuesUtility
  - Http

    - Controllers

      - Auth

        - RegisterController.php
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- public

Following code I am using in RegisterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   function showRegistrationForm(){
     $questionBuilder = App::make('Customfolder\Utilities\RegisQuesUtility');
   }
 }
```

But I am getting error Class Customfolder\Utilities\RegisQuesUtility does not exist.

Any suggestions what can be the reasons and possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path in `make` method as:

```
$questionBuilder = app()->make('App\Customfolder\Utilities\RegisQuesUtility');
```

Or

```
use App\Customfolder\Utilities\RegisQuesUtility;
// rest code
$questionBuilder = app()->make(RegisQuesUtility::class);
```

Comment: In both cases, Now it is giving error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App' not found

Comment: Also if I use your first suggestion, do I need to use use App at the top of page?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Now I have used `app()` method so you don't need to `use App` at the top of the class.